# C# Cannot escape quotes in a regex string

Tags: c#

I am trying to match quotes using regex but I don't manage to escape them in the `@string` - I am getting an error:

```
output = Regex.Replace(str, @"[\d-']", string.Empty);    // valid

output = Regex.Replace(str, @"[\d-'\"]", string.Empty);  // not valid!
```

This one is also does not work:

```
string str = "[\d-'\"]" // bad compile constant value!
```

Comment: `var output = Regex.Replace(str, @"[\d-'\""]", string.Empty); ` `""` for c# and a `\\` for Regex.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To escape a `"` in an a verbatim string, use `""`:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"[\d-'""]", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@` token suppresses `\` escaping. If you remove the `@` token it will work as expected, but you would have to escape the first backslash, i.e. `"[\\d-'\"]"`

Comment: Apologies, I missed the `\\d` token. In fact, DLeh's answer is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried out this piece of code

```
output = Regex.Replace("Ciao'\"", @"[\d-'""]", string.Empty);
Console.Writeln(output);
```

and this produced "Ciao" on the console screen. So, as DLeh just said, you should use the `""` to escape a quote.